# SQL SUM() on one field with other fields on other conditions (the most efficient way)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to retrieve total orders (in $$$) on particular date and at the same time need to find out how much was a cash transaction vs credit card transaction. **There are also others transaction type (eg. paypal) but does not need to be returned** (don't ask me why).

I have two choices, writing all in 1 query or go through cursor. Here is my 1 query

```
SELECT @TotalOrder = SUM([TotalValue]),
       @TotalCash = (SELECT SUM([TotalValue]) FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] dbChild WHERE (dbChild.[OrderId] = dbMain.[OrderId]) AND (dbChild.[PaymentType] = 0)),
       @TotalCard = (SELECT SUM([TotalValue]) FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] dbChild WHERE (dbChild.[OrderId] = dbMain.[OrderId]) AND (dbChild.[PaymentType] = 1))
FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] dbMain
WHERE [PaymentDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Is the query above ok? Alternatively, I can use cursor which loop through each record and accumulate the @TotalOrder, @TotalCash, and @TotalCard.

```
SELECT [TotalValue], [PaymentType]
FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] dbMain
WHERE [PaymentDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;

--then use cursor to loop through each of the record.
```

What do you think? Which one is the most efficient way? If both is not efficient, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method will most likely be the fastest, however you can refactor to use a single query:

```
SELECT @TotalOrder = SUM([TotalValue]),
       @TotalCash = SUM(CASE WHEN [PaymentType] = 0 THEN [TotalValue] ELSE 0 END)
       @TotalCard = SUM(CASE WHEN [PaymentType] = 1 THEN [TotalValue] ELSE 0 END)
FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] dbMain 
WHERE [PaymentDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Comment: That would be what I thought but some of the data comes from a child table that you have not shown.

Comment: @LoztInSpace no - both tables are the same. i.e. [dbo].[tblOrder]

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that the table was being aliased.  What a strange schema.